# What is an appropriate sealer for a Papercrete bench? 

Tags: concrete, product-recommendation, sealing, plaster, waterproofing

I've built a bench out of tires and papercrete two years ago. i've sealed it with lime plaster. in the past two years it held up against 500 m"m of rain in the winter and Mediterranean sun 7 month around. 
[image: bench out of tires and papercrete]
the mixture of the plaster layer below the lime is 50% cement Portland, 35% mashed paper, and 15% sand. 
Now the lime has started to peel
[image: lime has started to peel]
 and i want to take it all off and to apply a sealer that will have these characters:

1. i need to be able to find it in israel
2. it has to be environmentally approved
3. it needs to be fit for waterproofing concrete
4. it needs to last long (at least a 4-5 years)

Comment: Do you think the lime separated because it was somehow incompatible with what is underneath it?

Comment: @Judith Williams: I know now that lime is very hard to apply and it harder when the material is less/un-familiar. because i'm not a skilled plasterer i want to make it simpler for me and to use some kind of concrete sealer that will last long.

Comment: If you removed the plaster, I'm not sure you'd need to do anything to seal it beyond maybe a liquid concrete sealer of some kind.  If you want/like having it covered with plaster, I'm not sure what would work.  It looks like the plaster didn't bond with the concrete at all and just formed a shell which eventually cracked from water infiltration.

Comment: @Zach, what liquid sealer do you recommend for this job?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use something like this: [http://www.amazon.com/Rustoleum-239417-GAL-Stain-Sealer/dp/B0013TMC4E](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0013TMC4E)

But I really don't have much experience with these types of projects.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of like the patina it has now. What about some sort of epoxy that you'd typically use to seal concerete floors?

Comment: what kind of? do you have a brand name?

Comment: No particular brand names to recommend, but epoxy based concrete sealers are common.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the plain cement. Mix water and cement and it should be half solid

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to get old concrete to bond to new concrete. It will work for what ever you want to bond to concrete. Mix Elmers glue (plain white stuff, its just a polymer) with equal parts of water, 50/50 mix. Paint it on and let dry. Then what ever will bond with Elmers you can now use.